# React native Agora 3.5.0 TypeError: _reactNativeAgora.RtcEngineContext is not a constructor

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I updated our apss agora version to 3.5.0 because it wasn't working on ios 15. nwo it works on ios 15 but does not work on android.

Code starts exactly of this

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/react-native-agora/blob/master/example/src/examples/basic/JoinChannelVideo/JoinChannelVideo.tsx

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this._initEngine();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._engine?.destroy();
  }

  _initEngine = async () => {
    this._engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(
      new RtcEngineContext(config.appId)
    );
    this._addListeners();

    await this._engine.enableVideo();
    await this._engine.startPreview();
    await this._engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await this._engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
  };
```

And it says

```
TypeError: _reactNativeAgora.RtcEngineContext is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` which could be causing issues.